# What's the best way to get JSON-P data without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

I have an application that will return JSON-P data, and I have been communicating with it using jQuery's simple getJSON method:

```
$.getJSON("http://somedomain.com/&callback=?", this.callback);
```

I am bundling my code up into a library, and I love to not require jQuery. How easy would it be to re-write the getJSON function so that I can get cross-domain JSON-P data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can do something like

```
<script>
function mycallback(data) {
   //do something funky with 'data'
}

var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0);
var oScript= document.createElement("script");
oScript.type = "text/javascript";
oScript.src="http://somedomain.com/&callback=mycallback";
oHead.appendChild( oScript);
</script>
```

Comment: Do I need to worry about clearing away "stale" script tags each time I call this? I'll be calling it several times a second.

Comment: Not really. no. Although do want to arrange the the callbacks have unique names. Otherwise callbacks could easily get crossed, if requests are fired in quick succession. Thats why jquery usually handles creating the callback - so it can do manage the name.

Comment: I also realized I could probably add something like setTimeout(function() { oHead.removeChild(oScript); }, 1000); to the end of your code.